# Select record from mysql database via user input keyboard Java

Tags: java, mysql

My question is that I want to retrieve marks between a lowest and highest range from a database. The user is prompted to enter the lowest and highest range from the keyboard. I have a problem in my sql query where it is not recognising the cpa1 & cpa2 range that I have specified from the keyboard input. Please help.

See my codes below:

```
try{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Kindly enter the lowest CPA threshold : ");
    cpa1 = input.nextFloat();

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Kindly enter highest CPA threshold : ");
    cpa2 = input.nextFloat();

     rs = stt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE CPA BETWEEN `cpa1` and `cpa2` order by CPA asc");
     while(rs.next()){
         String id = rs.getString("student_id");
         String name = rs.getString("student_name");
         String gender = rs.getString("gender");
         float cpa = rs.getFloat("CPA");
         Date enrol = rs.getDate("enrollment_date");

         try{
             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("StudentRange.txt");

         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     input.close(); 
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What class is `stt`?  I highly doubt you can specify the `cpa1` and `cpa2` substitution values like you are doing with `executeQuery`.

Comment: stt is the Statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
rs = stt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM student WHERE CPA BETWEEN `cpa1` and `cpa2` order by CPA asc");
```

is not how you build a SQL query with parameters. Use a [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE CPA BETWEEN ? and ? order by CPA asc";
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setFloat(1, cpa1);
ps.setFloat(2, cpa2);
ps.execute(ps);
```

Comment: how can I sue prepared statement with insert?

Comment: At conn.execute(ps) .. It is giving me an error as "The method execute(PreparedStatement) is undefined for the type Connection"

Comment: Sorry, that's [`execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute--) on the `PreparedStatement`. But that is easy to find out if you read the JDBC tutorial and the documentation. SO is not a site where we solve your problem for you and you just sit back and wait for the solution. Do some work yourself!

Comment: Thanks man ! I edited your answer. The problem is resolved :)

Answer (score -1):

What about that:

```
rs = stt.executeQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM student WHERE CPA BETWEEN `%f` and `%f` order by CPA asc", cpa1, cpa2);
```

Comment: No! This opens a **huge** hole for [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Tichodroma The values are of type `float`, not `String`.  There is no security issue here.

Comment: @pathfinderelite Maybe in this special case. But it is a *very bad habit* to build SQL like this. Don't do it, even if you think you have everything under control.

Comment: I got no mysql running but i assume it has to be something like "SELECT * FROM student WHERE CPA BETWEEN %f and %f order by CPA asc" (without the quotes around the numbers)

Comment: @chris Please don't do this. It is *very bad advice*.

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around the substitution values, as they are numbers not strings.

Comment: @Tichodroma: sorry but i am working on the given problem. We can discuss about the security later on :)

Comment: @chris You are *not* working on the given problem. The correct way to build SQL for JDB is to use parameters. Using strings is just dangerous and stupid.

Comment: @Tichodroma I absolutely agree.  Prepared statements are still the way to go.

Comment: @Tichodroma: i read your edit on your answer just now. You're right, using prepared statements is more professional.